# Build Failure due to java heap size in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am  trying to deploy Extjs librarary(Javascript framework) into my web application.After copying Ext js and when I try to build I am facing build failure due to java heap size reason.

My Ext js Lib size is :101Mb removing these lib I am able to build successfully.

I have changed the following arguments in eclipse.ini file to

```
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   512M
  -showsplash
  org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
  512m
 --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vmargs
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
   -Xms512m
  -Xmx1024m
```

S[image: till I am facing build failure error.]

[image]

Still I am facing build fail errors.
I have increased the java heap in eclipse.ini is these heap memory is not sufficient to work on 100 mb file?.Kindly help me

Comment: Your Eclipse heap size and your application heap size totally different size. They independent each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your eclip's heap size is not enough for your application ....
here is little tweak

On Eclipse, **right click on the project ->RunAs-->Run Configurations**.., select the Apache Tomcat you want to run, clicks on the **Arguments tab**, **update the VM arguments** with the following options

```
-Xms<size> - Set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size> - Set maximum Java heap size
```

its shown below in an image [image]